# What counts as a good faith effort?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, trusts-and-estates

Please consider the following hypothetical situation:

The trustee of a trust is reviewing a monthly brokerage of the trust in her home. She lives alone. She leaves the statement in her kitchen. A couple of days later, she has a friend over for coffee who sees the statement and takes it. The trustee is unaware of her friend's action and has forgotten about the statement.

The friend then uses the  statement to take money from the trust. The terms of the trust say that the  trustee cannot be held liable if the trustee made a good faith effort. However, the beneficiary of the trust is not happy about the situation and the missing money, As such, he sues the trustee. Does the beneficiary have a good case? The trustee feels she made a good faith effort and therefore she is not liable.

Comment: How do you use a statement to take money from a trust, and even if that _is_ possible, why aren't you simply reporting the (hypothetical) friend to the police for theft and recovering the money that way?

Comment: @TripeHound From the statement you can get the account number and given that the friend takes money from the account and then spends it. The police find the friends but he does not have the money since he spent it. Also, given his legal problems he is likely going to jail/prison and will have trouble earning money to pay it back.

Comment: @MichaelHall You call up  the  brokerage firm and pretend to be a trustee on the account.

Comment: Most reliable institutions have safeguards against "pretenders" before they just dish out money.  Some sort of process to validate identity.  If they are that easily fooled they would open themselves up to major liability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The exclusion of liability is probably not applicable

Typically, the type of clause in a trust deed that grants the trustee indemnity is referring to indemnity from actions from third-parties, not from beneficiaries. That is, provided the trustee made “good faith efforts”, and aggrieved third-party takes action against the trustee, the trustee can look to the trust assets/insurance for protection.

The obligation that the trustee owes to the beneficiaries is fiduciary: to act prudently in their interests and to keep safe the assets entrusted. This is typically not a duty that can be watered down by the terms of the deed because it is at the heart of the trust relationship. It includes a duty of good faith but it also includes a duty of loyalty and a duty of care.

For the circumstances you describe, the duty of care is more relevant than the duty of good faith.

### Duty of care

The obligation on the trustee is to keep the assets of the trust safe and keep its secrets secret. The standard of care is that of a reasonably prudent person in the position of the trustee. From the description, it doesn’t seem that the trustee is a professional in the field so the standard is the standard of an ordinary person rather than the standard of a professional accountant or financial planner.

The beneficiary certainly has a reasonable argument that leaving confidential information which could allow direct access to the assets of the trust unsecured in a domestic kitchen for “a couple of days”, allowing other people to have access to the area, and “forgetting” about the information doesn't meet the standard of a reasonably prudent person entrusted with financial assets. Ultimately whether it does or doesn’t is up to the court, but its certainly a case worth running - the trustee should advise their insurer of a potential claim.

Answer (score 0):

The beneficiary has to prove *bad faith*. This could be proven by e.g. showing that the trustee benefitted from the theft, or by proving that the trustee knew that the thief had a criminal record. In the absence of bad faith, whatever remains is good faith.

Comment: Good faith and bad faith do not rub up against each other - there is a whole area in between that is neither.